# How can I map a spark RDD of json objects to another RDD which contains objects with only selected set of attributes

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark RDD (productList) of json objects in the following format.

```
{u'name': u'product_id', u'price': 12, u'quantity': 1}'
```

Now, I want to map this to another RDD which will contain only 'product_id' and total_amount which would be price*quantity. The following would results in the list of totalAmounts. But how can I also map product_id also along with total amount.

```
total_amount_list = productList.map(lambda x: x['price']*x['quantity'])
```

Comment: just try with `lambda x: (x['name'], x['price']*x['quantity'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
productList = sc.parallelize([
    {u'name': u'product_id', u'price': 12, u'quantity': 1}])

productList.map(
    lambda x: {'name': x['name'],  'total': x['price'] * x['quantity']}
).first()

## {'name': 'product_id', 'total': 12}
```

If your input data is a JSONL file then you should consider using `DataFrames`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

s = (
    '{"quantity": 1, "name": "product_id", "price": 12}\n'
    '{"quantity": 3, "name": "product_id2", "price": 5}'
)

with open('/tmp/test.jsonl', 'w') as fw:
  fw.write(s)

df = sqlContext.read.json('/tmp/test.jsonl')
df.withColumn('total', col('price') * col('quantity'))
```